# Derivative of function in Ad

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

If $G$ is a Lie group and $Ad: G \rightarrow End(\mathfrak{g})$ is the adjoint representation, what is the derivative of $Ad(\exp ty)(tH)$ in $t=0$ where $y, H\in\mathfrak{g}$?
I know that $ad$ is the derivative of $Ad$ in $t=0$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I appreciate your notation, but since $\operatorname{Ad}_{\exp ty} = e^{t \operatorname {ad}_y }$, you have
$$
\operatorname{Ad}_{\exp ty} ~ tH= e^{t \operatorname {ad}_y } tH , 
$$
so the derivative of this w.r.t. *t* is
$$
e^{t \operatorname {ad}_y } ( t \operatorname{ad}_y ~H+ H), 
$$
which reduces to *H* at *t*=0. Is this what you are unsure about?

If, instead, the original argument were *H* instead of *tH*, you'd get ad<sub>*y*</sub>  *H* .